# Why doesn't an associated account appear in my flair on Area51?

Tags: discussion, flair, area-51

I know I've not got a huge reputation at Server Fault so I suspect there is a minimum threshold around 200?

Server Fault appears on my [profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/314?tab=accounts#tab-top) so it is not an association issue, it just doesn't appear on my flair (see [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) for an example).

I've had a look at a [few](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/38/juan-manuel) [other](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/49?tab=accounts#tab-top) [users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/40/dr-gonzo) and their associated flair and it does appear like 200 might be the threshold.

Answer (score 3):

I see the answer is in the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **What about my reputation on other Stack Exchange Network sites?**
>
> If you have more than 200 reputation on associated accounts on other sites, we'll show that in your user information when you follow or commit to a proposal. This is an easy way for others to see at-a-glance your achievements across the entire network!