# How come I only see some of the sites next to my name on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t an associated account appear in my flair on Area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52119/why-doesnt-an-associated-account-appear-in-my-flair-on-area51)

Whenever it shows your name with your reputation and badges, underneath that it shows little icons of all the sites you participate in. For example, on [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters) you can see Jeff's name on the right with 6 different icons representing the different StackExchange sites he is a member of.

How come I have accounts on StackOverflow, SuperUser, and Meta, but I only see icons for the first two sites (i.e. there is no Meta icon)?

(My guess is that there is a minimum reputation you need in a site for it to appear there. If that is the case, what is the minimum?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 reputation is minimum requirement to display in your flair

[FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

> If you have more than 200 reputation
>   on associated accounts on other sites,
>   you'll earn a one-time bonus of 100
>   reputation, and **we'll show your
>   total reputation in your user
>   information**

Comment: Thanks, just wondering did you find this out by yourself or was it mentioned anywhere?

Comment: @eagle, It was mentioned somewhere, but still finding the link

Comment: @S.Mark: woops this is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52119/why-doesnt-an-associated-account-appear-in-my-flair-on-area51 do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: Exactly, closed it as exact duplicate

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do that. Is there anything I should do instead?

Comment: eagle, Oh, ok, If you only have delete option, you can delete it or just leave it, some people will come and close it.